# Apartment (condo) Ethernet Wiring advice

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, wired-networking

I moved into a new apartment—I’m in Brooklyn, NY—and connected to the internet through Time Warner Cable (coax cable) with a modem connected to a router. Every room  has a panel with a coaxial connection and a port labeled CAT5e.

I was hoping to find a way to take advantage of the CAT5e wiring to connect my different devices in the other rooms.

I've searched for a while to find out where the cables terminate and finally found CAT5e cables in the basement (It’s a condo and I’m on the 4th floor).

Only one cable is labelled with my apartment number on it, but there are a few other cables that are not labeled at all.

The cable seems to have some of it’s internal wires connected to a box that says “Verizon DSL” and to another Telephony box but I’m not sure.

This now feels way over my head. Can anyone either recommend what I can do or who I can talk to for help on this matter?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yoni, do you see any hardware in your apartment or in the basement that looks like this?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch-down_block#/media/File%3A66_block.JPG

Comment: Check closets or other locations for a device similar to the one I posted above.  Most wall jacks will terminate into punch down blocks.

Comment: Another thing to try is take a laptop around to each jack and plug an Ethernet cable from your laptop to the jack on the wall.  Look at the Ethernet adapter on your laptop after you connect the cable and see if you get a link light (usually green, could also be red or amber).  If you get a link light, you will know if that jack terminates somewhere else inside your building.  If you do not get a link light, it may still terminate somewhere but there might not be something on the other end to connect to.

Comment: Here is an example of what the link light I am referring to looks like http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/3518/Link-lights.JPG

Comment: What kind of modem do you have?  Is it actually within your apartment/condo?   Why do you think TWC is your ISP, but report that you find connections to a Verizon DSL box?  Is this really an apartment building or condo?  Are you a renter or an owner?  What does *" take advantage of the CAT5e wiring"* mean?

Comment: *"Every room has a panel with a coaxial connection and a port labeled CAT5e."*  -- Please provide a photo of such a *"panel"*.  *"Coaxial connection"* is probably an F-connector.  Is it for cable TV?  But what is a *"port"*?   Is it a RJ-45 or RJ-11 socket?  Is it for phone?

Comment: Hey everybody, thanks for trying to assist, let me try and clarify--
It's a condo building-- I own the apartment, only one apartment in my floor. The panel I was talking about looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/rMIQ7lh.png and I have one in each room. I'm connected with a TWC modem through the top connector (that I thought is called Coaxial) and then to a router.
I've tried connecting my laptop to every CAT5e jack and got no signal, so I started searching the apartment for a closet with those punch-down blocks like described and couldn't find any. Nobody in the building board knew anything...

Comment: ...so I started searching myself and found something that looks like a centralized communications room in the basement of the building. It has a TWC box, a Verizon box, and the mess of wires that I sent in the photos. I haven't touched anything. I also don't mean to touch anything, I just want to know what kind of professional should I try to bring to help me with that. Only one cable has a label that said "4th floor" but there are other unlabeled CAT5e cables that just end up loose.
What I want to do-- is to connect my router that's located in Room A to Room B. I don't want to move a cable...

Comment: ...between the living room and the office because they're far away from each other. I was hoping to use this jacks to leverage the current connection and connect them between each other.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> The cable seems to have some of it’s internal wires connected to a box that says “Verizon DSL” and to another Telephony box but I’m not sure.

There's no photo of this “Verizon DSL” box.
All I see are typical phone system equipment. The [NID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_device) demarcates the start of the premises wiring. The "network" in NID has nothing to do with DSL.
There's a fire alarm box, which is typically wired into the phone system.
There's nothing "DSL" in the photos, and nothing to indicate that the UTP is used for anything other than telco (i.e. the UTP cable is not used for Ethernet).

> I'm connected with a TWC modem through the top connector (...) and then to a router.

Does that confusing sentence mean that there's a coax cable from the wall plate to a modem, which is then connected to a (wireless?) router?

You're jumping the gun looking in the basement; you haven't identified what you have in the condo unit.
It's common to have a phone jack in every room.
You should open up several wall plates to inspect the cables(s).
A data jack would have a single UTP cable to a RJ-45.
Phone jacks are typically daisy chained, so there would be up- & down-stream cables.
Most likely those are phone jacks.
(BTW as an owner, you should complain to the builder about mixing almond or ivory color with white wall plates!)

> What I want to do-- is to connect my router that's located in Room A to Room B.
>   ...
>   I was hoping to use this jacks to leverage the current connection and connect them between each other.

If the UTP cable is used for phone service and/or is daisy-chained between the jacks, then you cannot use these jacks for a point-to-point connection (which is what you would need).